# Samba share write access allowed in chosen time - how to do it?

Tags: time, sharing, smb, schedule

I would like to configure a samba share to be writable only within scheduled time.
What is the best method to do it?

Regards
Kriss

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you give more details?  If all you need is to prevent samba from being active at certain periods, you could stop/start  the service as cron jobs;  'systemctl stop smbd` / 'systemctl start smbd`.  If only certain shares are to be accessible, it is more complex.

Comment: Be sure to provide adequate context and version numbers to allow the community to help you.  I'm not sure if you're looking for "full-time read and part-time read/write" but @Marc Vanhoomissen"'s suggestion along with "/usr/bin/crontab -e" should be able to get you to a solution.

Comment: I actually wanted implement this on raspberry pi (maybe in ubuntu in future). And was thinking about crontab but wanted to know if there maybe another way.
And the use for that is to have network backup drive. Periodic access is to prevent any potential encryption viruses to break my backups.
Anyway, thanks for help i'll research "the crontab way"